# INSERT statement Not Inserting

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am pretty new to android and I am trying to figure out why the following insert statement is not working. I think it probably has something to do with the method that's being called in my DBAdapter, but I'm not certain. When I run the app, I don't get any errors, but nothing is getting inserted in the table. Any ideas?

`String sql = "INSERT INTO strategyTotal(strategy_total)"
                + "VALUES ( ?) ";
        db.execSQL(sql, new Double[] { priceInput });`

Here's the method in DBAdapter:

```
public  void execSQL(String sql, Double[] Double) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public  void execSQL(String sql, Double[] Double) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This method does nothing. You probably meant for it to delegate the operation to `SQLiteDatabase`:

```
public void execSQL(String sql, String[] bindArgs) {
    db.execSQL(sql, bindArgs);
}
```

where `db` is an open-for-writing instance of `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: You have saved the day again! I just had to change it to Double to fit my datatype. ;) Thanks for the help! Man, I am really trying to get the hang of android java!

Answer (score -1):

the value for the parameter is never especified, my be you'll try this

```
ins.clearParameters();
ins.setInt(1,14);//set the exact data type that you are using
db.execSQL(sql);....
```

Comment: Sorry but where does `ins` come from? What type is it? You should at least invest time in an answer and explain more if you throw code around.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the first suggestion worked like a charm. :)